# why this doesn't throw an exception

Tags: c#

it's kind a simple question but i have the doubt see the code belows

```
public static String something;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (something == "blah")
                System.Console.Write("ok");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

i know that doesn't throw an exception but why? because the variable with the name something it's null and when you compare you're trying to get a reference with null. Can someone please explain to me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable, something, doesn't need to be instanced for that kind of comparison.  It knows how to compare itself to a null.

So it doesn't throw an exception because

null == "string"

is a valid comparison which returns false.

Answer (score 24):

Nothing is wrong here, since you're not trying to *dereference* `something`. You are getting its *value*, which is `null`. If you tried to *dereference* it (ie `something.somemethod()`) then an exception would have been thrown.

Answer (score 3):

This is IL code generated by compiler:

```
IL_0002:  ldsfld     string ConsoleApplication1.Program::something
IL_0007:  ldstr      "blah"
IL_000c:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
```

String.op_Equality Method:

public static bool operator == (string a, string b)

a - A String or a null reference

b - A String or a null reference

op_Equality allows to pass null references and doesn't throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare null to a string - the result is that they aren't equal. In this case Something is null - you don't have to "dereference" to use it in a comparison, the null value itself works.

Answer (score 0):

since the something variable is null, then comparing it to a string value is the same as saying

```
if(null == "blah")...
```

Clearly null and "blah" are not the same, so it will return false, it won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a nullable type.

So you in the given code you compare a **NULL** string to a string that contains the characters "**blah**" and you have no else statement.

Of course I would argue using == when you are trying to compare a string is wrong.

Technically "**Dog played ball with the boy\n**" and "**Dog played ball with the boy**\0" would not equate to true when using the == comparison.